# FastReport - ClearLastReport before or after showpreparedreport

Tags: c++, c++builder, fastreport, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I need clear the prepared report before or after calling frxReport->PrepareReport();

My report is a continuos report.

Ex.

```
//Clear here
for( Data->First(); ! Data->Eof; Data->Next() )
{       
    frxReport->PrepareReport(false);
}

frxReport->ShowPreparedReport();
//Or Clear Here.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PrepareReport(True)` will clear the previously prepared report.

Try something like this...

```
int reportCount = 0;
for( Data->First(); ! Data->Eof; Data->Next() )
{   
  Inc(reportCount);    
  frxReport->PrepareReport(reportCount == 1); 
}
frxReport->ShowPreparedReport();
```

This way, the first report will cause `PrepareReport()` to clear everything while subsequent reports will be added to the end.